# How can I get the package of a content provider from the query side of the model

Tags: android

I need to get the id of a content provider that is providing me with some data that I am querying from a query URI.

I guess this kind of goes against the idea of the content provider model - to abstract the client away from the content providers themselves, but I need to know which package has provided a certain piece of data.

I have the content resolver and I am performing a query against a URI. I need to know the id (uid, pid or package) of the application containing the content provider that is servicing the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be one content provider for a given authority.

To find out details of who handles a given authority, try `PackageManager` and `resolveContentProvider()`.